# Overwriting an object in a file with another object of same class using c++

Tags: c++, file-handling

I wrote a code wherein I am saving information into a file for retrieving it later on. There is a task for which i need to overwrite an object in file with new object ( Kinda like updating the saved information). But when I retrieve the information after updating it, the old info is printed. The object was not overwritten. Please verify my error. Here is the piece of code to write into the file:

```
HeaderInfo rx;   //This is the object which I want to write.
//headers is the pointer to file where all the objects are saved.
headers.read((char*)&rx , sizeof(HeaderInfo)); //First I read the old info from the file
headers.seekp(it->second->getHeaderLocation());  //go back to where the info was read from

//In the lines of code below, I modified the old information.
strcpy(rx.key,new_key.c_str());
rx.headerLocation = headers.tellp();
rx.dataSize = sizeof(HeaderInfo);
rx.freeSpace = 0;
rx.location =   it->second->getLocation();

//Now writing back the updated object to file.
writeEmptyHeader(rx , headers.tellp());
```

P.S. The pointers from where I read the file and want to write back to are correct. I verified them by printing the pointers. I just don't understand why the new object is not getting saved in file.

```
//This is the definition of HeaderInfo. It is basically a struct:
struct HeaderInfo{
    char key[MAX_KEY_LEN];
    long location;
    long headerLocation;
    long dataSize;
    long freeSpace;
};
```

Edited:
Here is the writeEmptyHeader function:

```
void DBManager::writeEmptyHeader(HeaderInfo& r , long fptr){

headers.write((char*)&r , sizeof(HeaderInfo));

}
```

P.S.: I know the name looks ambiguous. And I realized, it really is. But it just writes the header to file at location fptr. I made this function separately while debugging my code so didn't think much of it. Ignore the name! :P

Comment: There's nothing wrong in `writeEmptyHeader`? Maybe you should show it do us? The function name seems a little ambiguous to your use of it, does it write an empty header, or the structure provided in the first argument?

Comment: To get this clear: You are failing to update this only object of type `HeaderInfo` - did you already have a look into the `writeEmptyHeader` function. Please, at least share what *you have seen* there! ;-)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have edited my question. Please check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Wolf I am sorry for that ambiguous name, I didn't think it through! :P  I have edited my question and given the writeEmptyHeader function.

Comment: Are you writing it to the correct position? You don't write anything between the call to `seekp` and you writing the header structure? Does `getHeaderLocation()` return the correct position?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I checked the file pointers before and after writing the header. It matches perfectly as expected. If I was writing in the wrong place, other data would have been lost write. But I am not loosing any information nor my file gets corrupted. I verified that too by priting out all the data in the file.

Comment: Did you check the result of the actual `fwrite` function? Better: show us the type definition of `headers` and best also the corresponding `write` method.